# Xquery - Count elements

Tags: xquery

My XML schema is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE buildings[
<!ELEMENT buildings (building*)>
<!ELEMENT building (department+, name, type+, year)>
<!ATTLIST building id ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT department (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT type (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
]>
<buildings>
<building id='B1'>
<department>CSE</department>
<department>EE</department>
<name>Hoch</name>
<type>Teaching</type>
<year>1900</year>
</building>

<building id='B2'>
<department>CSE</department>
<name>HSC</name>
<type>Library</type>
<year>1900</year>
</building>

<building id='B3'>
<department>EE</department>
<name>Hoch</name>
<type>Teaching</type>
<year>1990</year>
</building>

<building id='B4'>
<department>Arts</department>
<name>NSC</name>
<type>Laboratory</type>
<year>1900</year>
</building>

</buildings>
```

I want to count departments which have buildings made in 1900. I want my output as:

```
CSE 2
EE 1
Arts 1
```

I have tried a few things and this the best I got. I am new to Xquery.

```
let $depts := doc("buildings.xml")/buildings/building/department
let $dept := doc("buildings.xml")/buildings/building[year="1900"]/department

for $x in distinct-values($dept)
let $count := count($x=(data($depts)))
return ($x, $count)
```

And the result I am getting is:

```
CSE 1 EE 1 Arts 1
```

What changes should I make to my query in order to get the result.
TIA.

Answer (score 2):

XQuery since 2014 supports a `group by` clause you can use:

```
for $dept at $pos in //building[year = '1900']/department
group by $key := $dept
order by $pos[1]
return ($key || ' ' ||  count($dept))
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMen

If you don't have XQuery 3 support you can use

```
let $dept := //building[year = '1900']/department
for $dist-dept in distinct-values($dept)
return 
    concat($dist-dept, ' ', count($dept[. = $dist-dept]))
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMen/1

Comment: count($dept[. = $dist-dept]  Can you tell me about this, not understanding why . = $dist-dept

Comment: @SUIIIII, first of all I would suggest to use the XQuery 3 approach of grouping with `group by`. If you are really stuck with XQuery 1, well, the expression `$dept` selects a sequence of `department` elements in a predicate like `$dept[. = expression]` the value of each element in the `$dept` sequence is compared to the value from the expression, in my suggested approach the used expression is the result computed earlier with `distinct-values`, that is, it is a sequence of distinct strings of department names.

Comment: And in XPath and XQuery any comparison `$a = $b` is true if at least one item in `$a` is equal to at least one item in `$b` so with `for $dist-dept in distinct-values($dept) return count($dept[. = $dist-dept])` the result is a sequence of integers of the count of departments for each distinct department value.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. I am not allowed to use XQuery 3 actually. My logical approach was the same except the syntactical part of [. = $x].